# How to print corresponding value of list2 in list1 when I have duplicate values?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
l=[10,36,54,89,12,17]
m=[3,7,3,0,7,0]
res=sorted(m)
for i in res:
    print(l[m.index(i)],i)
```

expected output:

> 89 0
>
> 17 0
>
> 10 3
>
> 54 3
>
> 12 7
>
> 36 12

but my output is

> 89 0
>
> 89 0
>
> 10 3
>
> 10 3
>
> 36 7
>
> 36 7

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.

Comment: AS the posting guidelines tell you, "make it easy for others to help you."  Get rid of whatever code isn't part of your question.  Your posted program ignores the PEP-8 guidelines for spacing and variables -- it's s sequence of dense text with meaningless names, indirect logic, and no explanations of the algorithm.  We have no idea *why* you expect a different output.  Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: the only possible indexes (values of `m.index(i)`)  are 0, 3 and 7, how can you expect to output the elements of *l* being at the other indexes ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest approach is to sort indexes rather than values:

```
l = [10,36,54,89,12,17]
m = [3,7,3,0,7,0]
indexes = sorted(range(len(m)), key=lambda idx: m[idx])
for i in indexes:
    print(l[i], m[i])
```